# Cards game - how to draw

Tags: android, performance, android-custom-view

I have to create a spider solitaire cards game for Android devices.

The main problem I face to start with is how do I set and arrange all the cards on the 'table', without using a `layout` for Views for each and everyone of the cards (taking into consideration that the amount of Views could exceed 150 at the same time on the screen).

I'm not looking at someone to give me an exact code to solve my problem, I just want some experienced ideas to start from to follow with my code. Do I have to create a `custom View`(the table) that would draw itself with all the views, or maybe.. is there any other option available (maybe some `library` to do such thing if you know one). Some clear main lines to consider for creating this app should suffice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use regular Android views for creating the game. You will get very pure performance and lots of problems with drawing game texture as you want. You should use OpenGL. You have few options here:

1. `Canvas` - it is already built in into Andorid SDK and you can use it without extra work. More details here: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html
2. Chose some game engine, for example [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) or [andengine](http://www.andengine.org/)